# Prove that a universal class $V$ is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

Prove that $V$ is a proper class, 
where $V$ is universal class.
Try to use these theorems:

(1)if $a$ is a set and $b\subseteq a$, then $b$ is a set.

(2) Russel class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Russel class is a subset of the universal class.
The Russel set is not a set.
If the universal class was a set, then the Russel class ...